# How to encrypt whole folder in Ubuntu?

Tags: encryption, ubuntu

I want to upload a folder to Google Drive. 
I don't want those Google bots to read my folder and files to make their company smarter (I assumed here that they read and learn from user's files too).

So I want to make sure that my folder was uploaded encrypted. Also, my folder is of 2 GB size. Please suggest an easy (less time-memory taking) way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure there are a plethora of ways of doing this depending on your seup and end-goal.  As Im a command line person here are a couple of ways I might do it.

1. If its for a static backup I might zip the files with a password, writing the output to a fuse mounted google drive.  So 1. Fuse mount google (for example using https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse), then 2. zip --encrypt /google-fuse-path/myfile.zip /path/to/files - this method allows easy recovery from any platform with ubiquitous tools as long as the passphrase is known.
2. If I wanted something I could interact with I might again set up a fuse mount as above, and then use file level encryption for example using cryfs. (see https://www.cryfs.org/tutorial/ for a step by step guide).  This basically does file encryption using google drive as the backend, while presenting unencrypted files in a different directory. You could do something similar with encfs or ecryptfs as well - but cryfs holds itself out as being thr most appropriate.
3. For the sake of completion I mention again using fuse and mounting an encrypted file as a block device. Using LUKS (or maybe truecrypt/veracrypt) - the issue here is that it requires to build the initial file, and this may be time consuming depending on how the parts interact.  Using LUKS is probably tbe most secure if you can keep track if the key file.